# Should I start with HTML or XHTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

So which one to start with, HTML or XHTML? I am a beginner and wants to have solid foundations of markup language but as I started learning I found some people use HTML and some XHTML.

Comment: Well as a beginner I don't have any clue of my own which one to choose between HTMl or XHTML and majority of developers voted for XHTML so I'll go with XHTML.

Comment: If you're a beginner you should use nothing other than HTML 4. XHTML is a fad that resulted from the XML fervour of 5-10 years ago. XHTML 2 died in fact. XHTML 5 is nothing more than a token gesture to placate those using XML for HTML and not recommended for use by the W3C. Despite the answer you've chosen there is very little reason to use it.

Comment: @cletus: HTML5 is a draft. Neither the HTML nor the XHTML serializations of HTML5 are recommended for use by the W3C.

Comment: @Alohci: It is not recommended to use complete HTML5, but you can quite safely add some aspects of it into your code

Comment: @Casebash. Indeed. In both HTML and XHTML serializations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XHTML is pretty much like HTML but non-sloppy. I really can't think of a reason besides laziness not to use it.

Comment: Someone does not agree: http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml

Comment: Most if not all highly seasoned developers would not agree with you, novice types, well yes they'd surely agree.

Comment: Here's a reason why you shouldn't really use XHTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770193/ies-xhtml-compatibility

Comment: @ntd, he just argues that sending xhtml as text/html may be a bad thing, it doesn't actually say -using- xhtml is bad.

Comment: @Daniel: actually that's exactly what he says. He explains that XHTML as text/html is bad and IE6 doesn't support XHTML+HTML. You lose several conveniences with XHTML (like HTML entities; XHTML entities are different). There is very little reason to use XHTML. So much so that XHTML 2 died and XHTML 5 exists only for compatibility reasons for those already using XHTML.

Comment: HTML is a well-defined language just like XHTML. Nothing sloppy about it. Either one can be implemented with mistakes and become invalid "tag soup."

Comment: @cletus not just IE6. No version of ie supports it.

Comment: HTML5. There's a reason right there.

Comment: Redundancy is not a proof of lack of laziness.

Answer (score 24):

Conventional wisdom has come sort of full circle on this point. Back in like 2002 everyone was gung-ho for XHTML but many people (including myself) didn't have good reasons why. It was just the cool new thing and everyone jumped on the bandwagon, started putting **XHTML** in their resume skills instead of just **HTML** which looked so plain and unimpressive.

What's happening now is, with HTML5 finished, people are starting to realize that there's nothing wrong with good old fashioned HTML. It's the language of the web. Here's the pros and cons of XHTML as I see them:

**Pro**

- Allows you to embed non-xhtml XML into your web page, such as an SVG element. This isn't possible with plain HTML.
- Allows you to easily parse your documents with an XML parser, which could obviate the need for hpricot or BeautifulSoup if say, you wanted to replace all H1 tags with H2 tags in your website templates.

**Con**

- IE doesn't understand the 'application/xhtml+xml' mime type, so as far as it's concerned you're sending malformed HTML.
- It's a little more verbose. `<br>` and `<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>` is neater looking, in my opinion, than `<br />` and `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`.

There must be some advantages to XHTML that I'm missing, but I myself use HTML for everything these days.

Comment: I don't know about that. SGML requires quotes, but I always thought HTML didn't. http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes

Comment: Yes. cletus is wrong. In general, using attributes without quotes is valid HTML. As it happens, I think quoting attributes is neater, but it's very much a personal preference and other reasonable people may disagree.

Comment: @Alohci: Doesn't strict HTML require quotes which means it is more a matter of future compatibility than personal preference?

Comment: @Casebash - No. HTML 4 didn't require it, and neither does HTML 5 in the text/html syntax. Easy to check. Copy <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"><title>test</title><p class=smith>Test</p> into http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and run. Even if a future HTML did make it a conformance requirement, HTML parsers (e.g. in browsers) would still need to support omitted quotes to be able to process huge swathes of the web. There is no future compatibility issue. XHTML served correctly as application/xhtml+xml does require them, of course.

Answer (score 15):

XHTML is only useful if you want to autogenerate/manage/validate/etc the HTML code with help of a *XML based tool*, such as a component based MVC framework (e.g. Sun JSF, Apache Struts, Microsoft ASP.NET, etc) or with XSLT. Parsing/formatting HTML programmatically is trickier than XML, because HTML allows here and there non-closing tags, e.g. `<br>`. XML is much easier to parse/format programmatically because it is required to be [*well-formed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element).

If you're just starting and/or hand-writing "plain vanilla" HTML, I would recommend to use [HTML 4.01 elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) with a [HTML5 doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#choosing). There's really no need to massage the HTML code into a XML format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The [HTML 5 elements](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/previewofhtml5) aren't widely supported yet, hence the recommendation to stick with HTML 4.01 elements. The HTML 5 doctype triggers the standards mode in most of the browsers, including IE6. The other benefit of HTML5 is that it allows closing shorttags like in XHTML. Also see [HTML5 spec chapter 3.2.2](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#elements):

> **Authors may optionally choose** to use this same syntax for void elements in the HTML syntax as well. Some authors also choose to include whitespace before the slash, however this is not necessary. (Using whitespace in that fashion is a convention inherited from the compatibility guidelines in XHTML 1.0, Appendix C.)

Basically, even if you write *pure* XHTML, using `<!DOCTYPE html>` would still make it valid (and trigger webbrowsers in the correct standards mode).

Comment: Here's a reason why you shouldn't really use HTML 5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413114/html-vs-xhtml-does-it-still-matter

Comment: D'oh. I didn't said "HTML 5 elements", I just said "HTML 5 doctype".

Comment: Nice, your answer compliments my answer. "XML based tool" was the part I was missing.

Comment: Using an HTML5 doctype excludes the use of a mature validator that tests against a stable specification.

Comment: D'oh, I didn't said "HTML 5 elements", I just said "HTML 4.01 elements".

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to *learning* on or the other, there's really rather little between them. XHTML is essentially a subset of HTML that encourages (or rather requires) stricter standards -- specifically, it's an application of the XML standard to HTML. As such, any valid XHTML is also valid HTML (for the most part at least).

In my opinion, the distinction between XHTML and HTML isn't really that important. What *is* important, however, is to write consistent and efficient markup, and this is what the XHTML standard was designed to encourage. It doesn't matter whether you label you code as XHTML or HTML, just as long as it's well-written.

The main feature of XHTML is simply that it requires a high standard of quality in your code, *but this is something you should be doing anyway in HTML*.

Comment: "As such, any valid XHTML is also valid HTML". No it isn't. Prior to HTML5, it is impossible to create a single document that is both valid XHTML and valid HTML. XHTML must include a namespace declaration attribute, and that would be an invalid attribute in HTML.

Comment: Hence "for the most part at least". For practical purposes (and certainly for a beginner), it's still reasonable to say that XHTML is a subset of HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't agree. A construct like <div /> will do one thing in XHTML and something different when treated as HTML. To describe XHTML as a subset of HTML is to deny that, and thereby cause confusion in beginners. I prefer to describe HTML and XHTML as sibling languages, with a common vocabulary but different syntaxes.

Answer (score 3):

XHTML is for a-type people who think XML looks more "neat" than plain-ol HTML.

But really, it doesn't matter that much. You can switch from using one to another faster than it would take you to get some lunch.

Comment: For small sites yes, for large, it isn't so easy

Comment: I meant in your brain, not in a codebase.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 4.01 would be your best bet since learning in stages would allow you to see a clearer picture of whats really happening behind the scenes and deep within the markup. Once you have a clear view and lengthy understanding of the HTML 4.01 you can then move to XHTML 1.0.

Comment: So they should learn the poor habits that HTML allows then move to the better standard?

Comment: Think of it anyway you'd like, the reality of the matter is if you don't know where we are coming from you wont be well suited to know where we are going.

Comment: What "poor habits" does HTML allow?

Comment: HTML 4 doesn't teach poor habits. It teaches the markup that has the widest possible support. XHTML is a self-indulgent and pointless distraction 99% of the time.

Comment: @mastermind: can you explain why HTML 4.01 is better for understanding what's happening behind the scenes? I think most people would picture the tree-structured DOM better as XML than as HTML where some tags are often omitted. To a beginner, the determination of which tags can be omitted seems very arbitrary.

Comment: The most important thing is to use validation, even as a beginner

Answer (score 1):

Start with HTML, but use a validator. In HTML5, everyone seems to be focusing on the HTML, rather than the XHTML serialisation.

- As I explain in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557827/whats-the-need-for-xhtml/3194352#3194352), the designers of XML wanted to enforce higher coding standards and making parsing easier, but that only works if almost everybody switches. Instead of relying on your browser to enforce code quality, rely on validation.
- Due to limited XHTML support in Internet Explorer <=8, pretty much everybody serves XHTML as text/html. This effectively restricts you to a subset of HTML and XHTM and requires you to follow [compatibility guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#compatGuidelines). You could choose what format to serve based on user agent instead, but this is messy.

Given the limited advantages, I strongly recommend HTML, especially if you are a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and XHTML are the same language, with slightly different syntaxes. Once you know one, you know the other.

It really doesn’t matter.

Comment: It isn't super important to get this right for a beginner, but even so going with HTML will be easier for a beginner

Comment: “HTML will be easier for a beginner” — how?

Comment: @Paul: Dual serving based on the accept header is messy. XHTML served as HTML requires you to follow [compatibility guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#compatGuidelines). Either option is quite complex

Comment: @Casebash: I guess the compatibility guidelines would be confusing if you’re coming from an XML background. If not, I don’t think you’d even notice them.

Comment: @Paul: Are you saying that we should teach XHTML without teaching XML?

Comment: @Casebach: Depends really. If you’re actually going to be using XHTML as XML at any point, then learning XML would help. But if you’re just writing XHTML for the web, then you’re not actually writing XML, so I reckon you could quite happily skip XML knowledge. And really, what is there to XML itself (i.e. ignoring any specific XML languages)? It’s just a set of syntax rules, right?