# get .css file from a sub folder

Tags: css, jsf, facelets

In Netbeans I have a sub folder called `css` and a file in it called `testcss.css`.

How do I get Facelets file from root to access the `testcss.css` file?

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/testcss.css" title="style" />
```

My directory structure is:

```
Root (not a folder)
    css (folder)
      testcss.css
```

A screenshot of the structure is available [here](http://i1081.photobucket.com/albums/j348/west-wot/Directory_zps2ce00b84.png).

Comment: You could also try ../testcss.css, I think.

Comment: Based on the screenshot and the question history, you're using JSF/Facelets. I've added the appropriate tags to the question. Remember, Facelets is XHTML, but XHTML is not Facelets, so it's absolutely wrong to use the XHTML tag. A lot of users in the XHTML tag are naive and do not understand that it's essentially a template to ease HTML code generation by a XML based tool and incorrectly assumes that XHTML is been used "as-is" (which they incorrectly also do in real world, see also e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1989527) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3869174) answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put CSS (and JS and image) resources in `/resources` folder (create one if it doesn't exist).

```
Web Pages
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |-- resources
 |    |-- css
 |    |    `-- style.css
 |    |-- js
 |    |    `-- script.js
 |    `-- img
 |         `-- logo.png
 |-- index.xhtml
 :
```

Once accomplished that, you should be able to reference the CSS (and JS and image) resources using the appropriate JSF components [`<h:outputStylesheet>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html) (and [`<h:outputScript>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) and [`<h:graphicImage>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/graphicImage.html)) as follows:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript name="js/script.js" />
<h:graphicImage name="img/logo.png" />
```

No need to fiddle with relative paths. JSF will automagically generate the proper URL.

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template/)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)
- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code/)

Comment: Thank you, have helped a lot ! have now changed all my css etc to the above format

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the correct path.

for example if your files are organized:

```
ROOT
   CSS(FOLDER)
      styles.css 
   UPLOADED(FOLDER)
      index.html
```

if you are trying to access the styles file from index.html you need to:

```
href="../css/styles.css"
```

Comment: Or you could use a root-relative path like `/css/testcss.css`.

Comment: could you write out how your files are organized? or take a screenshot of all the necessary folders expanded and update your question?

Comment: Updated, will add a screen grab in a sec

Comment: Updated with link to screenshot