# Can't reference my javascript file into my xhtml template

Tags: javascript, jsf, xhtml

I want to reference a **javascript file** named "primefaces_locales.js" into my **template.xhtml**

The javascript file is into "**/myApp/src/main/webapp/resources/js/primefaces_locales.js**"

I've wrote this, but it doesn't work (I can see that the js file is not found when I run the application):

```
<h:head>
        <script language="javascript"
            src="../resources/js/primefaces_locales.js" />
....
```

Comment: Please do a research before asking any question, see this [Resources (Library) In JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: Also, XHTML doesn't have the `language` attribute. Use `type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the reply... But actually the solution was the best explained here: [get .css file from a sub folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484985/get-css-file-from-a-sub-folder/14486766#14486766) since I don't use themes/libraries mentioned in the mkyong link.