# Using f:view to override default contentType - cons?

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

I use a lot of jQuery plugins in my JSF 2.0 application and not all of them generate HTML which can successfully pass through the strict XHTML checks of webkit browsers. So the solution is to actually get into the plugin's code and correct it so that it generates a valid HTML, which is a very time consuming process in itself, or, wrap the contents of generated HTML in `<f:view contentType="text/html">`. The latter is quite straight forward and it works.
Are there any cons of using `<f:view>` to override the content type in such a manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF defaults to the closest media type in the [`Accept`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) header as is been sent by the webbrowser. If the URL matches `*.xhtml`, then it will usually end up to be `application/xhtml+xml` in some browsers and `text/html` in other browsers. You can without any problems force it to be `text/html`, most browsers treat XHTML as HTML anyway. Forcing to `application/xhtml+xml` is however a different story: MSIE doesn't support it in any way.

#### See also:

- [IE's XHTML Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770193/ies-xhtml-compatibility)
- [Internet Explorer wants to download the webpage of GuessNumber example application instead of displaying it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009531/internet-explorer-wants-to-download-the-webpage-of-guessnumber-example-applicati)
- [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5)