# Force JSF to escape special characters in unicode

Tags: html, jsf, unicode

Is it possible to force JSF to escape special-characters in the unicode-way `&#228;` rather than the named-entity-way `&auml;`?

Background: Some old mobile devices (e.g. a HTC-Desire with Android 2.3.4) refuse to display a page containing named-entities:

> This page contains the following errors ... Entity 'auml' not defined.

The page has a HTML5-Doctype and [according to the specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#character-references) `auml` is a [valid predefined character-reference](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#named-character-references).
So I think this is a browser bug but that does not help me here.

What I tried is to replace special-characters with their unicode-representation. But if I place an `ä` or even an `&#228;` in the view JSF will render me an `&auml;`.
If I place the entity-mapping in the doctype (I know that this should not be done in a HTML5-doctype) the behaviour gets really strange:

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY auml "&#228;">
    <!ENTITY mdash "&#8212;">
    ...
]>
```

This will result in a correct HTML5 doctype without the mapping. But a `&mdash;` will be replaced by `&#8212;` while an `&auml;` won't be replaced.

Has anybody an explanation for that or is there the possibility to configure JSF to allways render unicode-escaped entitites?

Comment: What JSF impl/version? Can't reproduce with Mojarra 2.1.25 in its default trim. I however recall encoding inconsitenties like this in ancient versions. This can also happen if you've explicitly set the `<f:view encoding>` to a non-Unicode-compatible encoding, but that would be a too obvious cause.

Comment: Android 2.3.3 renders `&auml;` fine for me... you're not serving it as an XML MIME type are you? Despite HTML5's sad attempts to fudge the issue, `auml` and the other HTML entities are not predefined in XML and should be rejected by XML parsers.

Comment: You're right @BalusC. Setting ```<f:view encoding="ISO-8859-15">``` would be a too obvious cause. But obviously not for me. Thanks for the hint and shame on me. So the question is answered although my problem is unresolved.

Comment: Thanks @bobince for retesting this. The content-type is text/html with charset ISO-8859-15 so the document should not be treated as XML. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @lefloh: weird, does it repro for you just on a normal `text/html` page with `&auml;` on? I can't believe they'd've broken such basic behaviour in a point release...

Comment: @bobince this is really weird. Can not reproduce it with a simple text/html page but can reproduce it with a simple JSF-page with `<f:view encoding="ISO-8859-15" /> `. Seems like adding `contentType="text/html"` there can fix it but I don't understand why. This is the default and the headers sent don't change. Will retest it in the production-near test-environment but will have to wait for next deployment next week.

Comment: Ah... `contentType` doesn't necessarily default to `text/html` so you should set it manually anyway. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375669/using-fview-to-override-default-contenttype-cons). Disastrous piece of bad design in JSF if you ask me—going to XML mode will easily break half your JavaScript if you're not expecting it, aside from the entity issue.

Comment: OMG! This explains everything! I really did not know this… Thanks @bobince! You really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if you've set `<f:view encoding>` to a non-Unicode compatible encoding.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<f:view encoding="UTF-8">
```

Since JSF2 on Facelets, this is the default value already, by the way, so you can safely omit it if you're indeed using JSF2 on Facelets.